# Loading data to Contact entity is very slow

Tags: dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

I am trying to load data in to the contact entity using SSIS and the KingsWay CRM Destination component. The problem is that it is taking too long.

**The setup:**

CRM: 365 sandbox environment hosted in the cloud (West Europe). 
Batchsize: 100 
Threads: 2 
All custom plugins related to the entity are deactivated.

It takes 4 minutes to send 262 rows.

On other entities I can send a couple of thousand of rows faster than this.

What could be the issue, and how can I debug it further?

**Update**

It seems that removing the mapping to the fields:

FirstName 
LastName 
EmailAddress1

reduces the load time from 4 minutes to 11 seconds.

Are there some system plugins that are triggering on this?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to check if there are any workflows or plugins firing on create or update of a Contact.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I used the plugin registration tool to disable all steps related to the contact entity. I used View -> Display by Entity to make sure that I found everything related to contact. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Check for duplicate detection rules.

Comment: When you enter First and Last Name, the system calculates the Full Name field. +1 on checking dupe detection.

Comment: @Aron is there something I can do to prevent it from being calculated, ie if I pass the full name myself?

Comment: I've never tested whether importing the full name suppresses the auto-generation of it. I suspect no, but it's worth giving it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If you already took care of dupe contacts in your import file, then unpublish the Duplicate detection rule for contact (OOB based on Name & Email):

> Settings>Data management>Duplicate detection rules> select Entity type: Contact

You can import the file, afterwards you can publish the duplicate detection rule again to ensure data governance. If you want you can run the Duplicate detection job once import is done.

Otherwise turn off org level settings using below steps:

> Settings>Data management>Duplicate Detection Settings>Enable duplicate detection - uncheck the option: During Data import

Refer [this](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/colinmaitland/2013/08/04/deduplication-of-data-during-import-using-data-import-wizard-and-duplicate-detection-rules) and [this](https://www.catapulterp.com/bad-data-ends-mastering-art-crm-duplicate-detection/)

Comment: There is a system rule called "Contacts with the same first name and last name" and a custom rule that checks the email address. However, they all have the unpublished state. Could they still slow down performance, even when in this state?

Comment: I tested disabling duplicate detection rules during data import, and it did not help. So far ignoring the fields in the CRM component is the only thing that improves performance

Comment: Can you try only with FN, then only with LN, then only with Email. So we can isolate the issue. Also see if you can eliminate the possibility of data issues? I doubt the composite field Full name can be filled manually..